# alaphbet_numeric__pattern using python

Tags: python

I want logic for alphanumeric pattern anybody knows the logic send the code
I tried the code not worked

```
def triangle(n):
   k=n-1
   for i in range(1,n+1):
      for j in range(k):
         print(" ",end="")
      k=k-1
      for p in range(i):
         print("*",end=" ")
      print()
print("Enter number of rows")
r=int(input())
```

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you expect to happen? If you want to print out the triangle you just have to call the function like so:

```
def triangle(n):
   k=n-1
   for i in range(1,n+1):
      for j in range(k):
         print(" ",end="")
      k=k-1
      for p in range(i):
         print("*",end=" ")
      print()
print("Enter number of rows")
r=int(input())

# This is where you call the function
triangle(r)
```

Comment: You might want to remove the 1st question, that could be considered slightly offensive (which is contradictory in a post designed to help :))